# How to resolve Unit test for this method whit Assertions or mocks?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm working on this method and trying to add a unit test for it. However, I don't have any idea about result, so I'm trying to verify the variable `cantidad` with `assertNotNull` to resolve the distinct condition, but can not continue.

```java
cantidad = mapsCodigoError.getHaspMapCodigos().size();
if (cantidad != 0) {
    hashMapCodigos = (HashMap<Totalcodigo, Integer>) mapsCodigoError.getHaspMapCodigos();
    Iterator<Entry<Totalcodigo, Integer>> entries = hashMapCodigos.entrySet().iterator();
    List<ValorCodigoOrdenado> listaEstatus = new ArrayList<>();
    listaEstatus=recuperarError(entries,listaEstatus);
    Collections.sort(listaEstatus);
    ValorCodigoOrdenado value;
    for (int i = 0; i < listaEstatus.size(); i++) {
        valor=listaEstatus.get(i);
        listaValoresEstatus.add(value);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can unit test with your method:

- interactions with other methods - mainly if they are from different classes, e.g. the calls to

  - `mapsCodigoError.getHaspMapCodigos().size()`
  - `mapsCodigoError.getHaspMapCodigos()`
- that `recuperarError(entries,listaEstatus)` calculates the right result when given specially crafted `entries`
- that the result of `recuperarError` is sorted later in the method
- that `listaValoresEstatus` gets filled in the values from `listaEstatus`

I don't see how the variables "come into" the method, nor how they can be accessed later on, but I can see that the code could get some improvements:

- `hashMapCodigos` probably should be only of type `Map<Totalcodigo, Integer>` except if you rely on properties or methods that only `HashMap` provides.
- Why does the result of `mapsCodigoError.getHaspMapCodigos()` have to be cast, it looks like it should return exactly the type that you need in this method?
- Why does `recuperarError` only take an `Iterator` for the first parameter and not a `Collection` or maybe a `Set`? Except for very special cases there are better ways to process all items of a Collection than a `Iterator`
- `ValorCodigoOrdenado value` should be declared inside the for-loop, because you don't need it afterwards. ("minimize visibility")
- To get all values of `listaEstatus` into listaValoresEstatus`, probably a` listaValoresEstatus.addAll(listaEstatus)` would be enough - without a loop - except if some magic boxing/unboxing or automatic casting of values happens in the loop. Even then a "foreach" loop would look nicer.
- Is there a typo because there is a declaration of `value` but a usage of `valor` in the loop? Looks as if this code would not compile at all.